# How to display load image on html page after selecting and until query is work and when request is complete hide image ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to display load image on html page after selecting and until query is work and when request is complete hide image ?**

I have web page which fetching information from a database

When a user selects a user in the dropdown list above, a function called "showUser()" is executed. The function is triggered by the "onchange" event:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page on the server called by the JavaScript above is a PHP file called "getuser.php".

The source code in "getuser.php" runs a query against a MySQL database, and returns the result in an HTML table:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**how to display load image on html page after selecting and until query is work and when request is complete hide image ? **

I try to use code in `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({   

beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
     $("#loading").show();
},

complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
 $("#loading").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="loading">
    <p><img src="loading.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work on my page

Comment: try using simple ajax calls like $.get from jquery in your function showuser().

Comment: please explain in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery.

```
     <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
  function getuser(str){
     $.ajax({   
      url: "getuser.php?q="+str,
      beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         $("#loading").show();
      }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
     $("#txtHint").html(data);
     $("#loading").hide(); });
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='users']").change(function () { 
   getuser($("option:selected", this).val()); });
   });
   </script>
   </head>
```

Your body should be like this.

```
   <body>
   <select name="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
   </body>
```

Comment: I need to call getuser function?

Comment: i changed my answer i hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but it doesn't work, I insert it in html page in <head> tag

Comment: sorry I'm newbie, please explain

Comment: You need $(document).ready(function(){}) to know when DOM is fully loaded so you can listen for change events like this. you can read for ready function here http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and for ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ here  there is plenty of examples how to make ajax requests.

Comment: its work, i just use 
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">

Comment: I have just one more truble, now getuser.php called twice
I add mail function to this script and all messages are sending twice

Comment: Did you remove onchange="showUser(this.value)" on the select tag ?